# How to refactor assignments to satisfy Rubocop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubocop

I am assigning some values to an newly created (Icalendar-) Object:

```
def map_to_cal_event
    e             = Icalendar::Event.new
    e.dtstart     = to_icaldate start.to_datetime
    e.dtend       = to_icaldate self.end.to_datetime if self.end.present?
    e.summary     = title
    e.description = description
    e.url         = timetable_url
    e.categories  = categories
    e.location    = location

    e
  end
```

Using Rubocop it is complaining about
`Metrics/AbcSize: Assignment Branch Condition size for map_to_cal_event is too high. [<8, 21, 1> 22.49/17]`

It seems a very common assigment to me.
So, How to refactor this method to satisfy rubocop? Or should i put it in the ignore-list?

Comment: Is it possible to initialize this object and pass all that arguments to `new` instead of assignments?

Comment: Yes, with some helper method for the dtend-value it should be possible.  But is it more readable and clean then?

Comment: Yes, probably is more readable just `MyObject.new(args)` than `my_object = MyObject.new; my_object.attr1 = attr1; .....  my_object.attr1000 = attr1000`

Comment: ah no, looking into the docs it its not possible for icalendar initialisation.. but this would be clean indeed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should satisfy Rubocop, define a new event in a separate method using the [`tap`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/tap) method with a block then pass another block to it with all the assignments.

```rb
def map_to_cal_event
  build_new_cal_event do |e|
    e.dtstart     = dtstart
    e.dtend       = dtend
    e.summary     = title
    e.description = description
    e.url         = timetable_url
    e.categories  = categories
    e.location    = location
  end
end

def build_new_cal_event(&block)
  Icalendar::Event.new.tap(&block)
end

def dtstart
  to_icaldate(start.to_datetime)
end

def dtend
  to_icaldate(self.end.to_datetime) if self.end.present?
end
```

Comment: This makes sense to me, but rubocop complains about:
```C: [Correctable] Style/ExplicitBlockArgument: Consider using explicit block argument in the surrounding method's signature over yield.
    Icalendar::Event.new.tap do |e| ... ``` :-/

Comment: Rubocop is telling you to change `build_new_cal_event` to make it say that it accepts a block. You can change its definition to `def build_new_cal_event(&:block)` and replace `yield e` with `block.call(e)`.

Comment: I updated my answer to satisfy the `Style/ExplicitBlockArgument` rule.

Answer (score 0):

I've not done optimizing ABC metrics yet, but one thing that I would try here just by looking at the code is replacing the functions for dtstart and dtend by a helper function by itself, i.e.

```
def map_to_cal_event
  e             = Icalendar::Event.new
  e.dtstart     = dtstart_time
  e.dtend       = dtend_time
  e.summary     = title
  e.description = description
  e.url         = timetable_url
  e.categories  = categories
  e.location    = location

  e
end

def dtstart_time
  to_icaldate start.to_datetime
end

def dtend_time
  to_icaldate self.end.to_datetime if self.end.present?
end
```

(Posted as an answer instead as a comment to be able to format the code)

Comment: This is working an rubocop is not complaining anymore :-)